# Как в автотесте выключить интернет

Tags: test-automation, pytest, appium

Использую Pytest, Appium

Какой метод использовать, чтобы во время работы теста, строчка кода выключала сеть на девайсе. Необходимо для того чтобы проверить работу приложения оффлайн

Answer (score 0):

Этой строчки оказалось достаточно:
driver.set_network_connection(0)